# Downvoting for a perfectly legitimate question just because one thinks the OP is misbehaving in other threads

Tags: discussion

One member wrote this is a very proper reason to downvote.
He even implied that it is a very proper reason for voting to close.
And he actually did vote to close, for example, as shown in [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4936/voting-to-close-a-question-because-one-thinks-it-is-extremely-specialised)(
[the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183522/unramification-of-a-prime-ideal-in-an-order-of-a-finite-galois-extension-of-an-a) was closed almost a month after the frequent editing problem was solved by introducing [the sandbox](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4666/sandbox-for-drafts-of-long-complex-answers)).

What do you think?

Here is [the conversations](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/does-getting-a-lot-of-downvotes-have-actual-effects-on-a-question-or-the-op) with him.

Comment: Voting to close this as non-constructive. Nothing can be done with the way people vote. It took me sometime (about a year) to realize this and be indifferent about this.

Comment: @Marvis What about voting to close a perfectly legitimate question?

Comment: I think, as a discussion topic, it would be interesting to know how the community feels about this. The way a jury votes cannot be controlled, however, they are given guidelines not to consider prior crimes when judging guilt. In the same way, we can suggest that perfectly good questions should not be downvoted due to prior transgressions of the author (if that is the community's feeling).

Comment: @robjohn: Generally I might have agreed. However in this particular case I can't. We are talking about the case of a user which not only grossly misused almost every possible feature, but also insisted repeatedly that he did nothing wrong. When words no longer help, something has got to give. Or to compare this to a jury duty... on the third offense, the punishment is more severe.

Comment: That is *clearly* an invalid reason for down voting. Why is this question closed as not constructive?

Comment: @Yury: No offense, but I don't think that you have been on the site long enough to understand the issues here.

Comment: @Asaf: That's true that I joined math.SE just a few months ago (though I have been a member of other math forums for many years). Frankly, it seems very wrong if somebody down votes a post or answer because of a personal dislike of the poster (or by other unrelated reasons). If it is acceptable here, it would be a good idea to tell novice users like me about that.

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, more or less in the spirit of Robjohn's comment above.  Regards,

Comment: I have voted to reopen this question, in the spirit of Robjohn's comment, and out of respect for $Yury 's concern.

Comment: Also relevant to this thread: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4703/downvoting-only-for-personal-preference-to-the-op (this meta question is one vote shy from deletion).

Comment: (The previous meta thread is now deleted, but for 10K users, I think it's still useful)

Comment: @Yury: You should read the answers by Hurkyl, Michael Greinecker and myself. You may also be interested in reading the comments on Kaveh's answer, and the links appearing in my answer if you have some time to kill and nothing better to do... :-)

Comment: You keep claiming that I have issues with *you*, as a person. I don't, I have issues with your behavior. But it starting to look as though *you* have an issue with *me*.

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I don't have issues with you as a person. I have issues with your behavior towards my perfectly legitimate questions.

Comment: @JasperLoy You think that it is impossible to want to enforce no-smoking rules without personally disliking the smokers?

Comment: @Makoto: I don't have a problem with **some** of your questions, but I am truly tired of seeing how you behave as if the site is your own personal website. It's not. It's a community. And the insistence on lack of **communication** makes you a lousy **community** member. Do note the similarity in the two boldface words in my previous sentence.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I would like to know what's wrong with my behavior. Please open a meta thread to discuss it.

Comment: @Makoto: I have opened a meta thread. Several people opened meta threads. Look at my answer below, instead of just downvoting it and cursing the screen that you are being prosecuted. Do you think that you were issued a suspension during the summer for no reason? (which only recently you have chose to complain about, for some strange reason.) Or do you think that all those people who voted my comments, answers, and threads and downvoted your posts are just sock puppets that I created, or people I have brainwashed somehow? You are *so* blind that you can't admit that you **may** have done wrong?

Comment: As I said many many times before. You are impossible to discuss.

Comment: Furthermore, there is absolutely no point in opening a meta thread. This is **not your site** and I am tired of starting meta threads related to your specific and unprecedented behavior. I did it once, and it was tiresome. Secondly you will just claim that you are innocent of any point, and you are just trying to do some math, and for some unknown reason people prosecute you. **ENOUGH!!** People have better things to do on this site than to explain to you why you are being impossible. [...]

Comment: [...] I wrote in the comments, *others* have written in the comments, to many of your meta threads, what is wrong with your behavior. If you are incapable of reading and understanding those comments which are neither hinting nor sugarcoating, then something is wrong with your ability to read and understand what other people are saying. With that I cannot help, and no amount of meta threads will help.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "I have opened a meta thread." Your thread brought several different issues at the same time.
As someone pointed out there, that's no good for discussion.
Please open a new thread treating only one issue regarding my behavior which you think is harmful to this site.

Comment: Makoto, as someone pointed in that thread it's the combined behavior which is problematic. You cannot separate it more than you can separate hot water from brewing tea.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I think the frequent edit problem was solved. What problems are unsolved?

Comment: @Makoto: One unsolved problem is that criticisms of you get turned into big incidents. Another unsolved problem, IMO, is the frequent edit problem -- I am not aware of you having given any semblance of appreciating (or even understanding) why others found it troublesome, and I have little confidence that you would refrain from resuming such activities if you ever found the sandbox inconvenient.

Comment: @Hurkyl "One unsolved problem is that criticisms of you get turned into big incidents."

I don't understand this. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Makoto: There is a lot of negativity centered on your questions, answers, and comments. This thread, for example.

Comment: @Hurkyl I'm asking the reasons for the downvotes and the votes to close for my perfectly legitimate questions. What are the problems unsolved causing those?

Comment: @Makoto: ... that it's turned into a circus. I believe your oblivious act is a significant cause. But whether it's your fault or not is a problem that needs solved.

Comment: **OH MY GOD**, I just went to see that one old thread I opened which Makoto claims that the problem mentioned in it was already solved...[And it suddenly hit me](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/where-is-the-fine-line-between-using-and-misusing#comment18526_4749) that I have been having the same back-and-forth deaf argument with Makoto for *at least* five months. This is the definition of insanity. Why do I keep thinking that maybe this argument Makoto will finally understand? I don't know, but I sure think that most people would give up on you as a person.

Comment: There are currently three votes to reopen this question. It has already been closed twice with one reopen in between. I would be interested in hearing a strong argument for why this should be reopened yet again. What is the intended/expected outcome of such a move?

Comment: @cardinal, maybe if we reopen the thread Asaf and Makoto will both manage to get suspended, and we can have some peace here. For a while.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You did not answer my question. What *are* the problems unsolved if any?

Comment: @Hurkyl "Another unsolved problem, IMO, is the frequent edit problem"
Why do you think so?

Comment: @cardinal "I would be interested in hearing a strong argument for why this should be reopened yet again."
Why do you think this should be closed?

Comment: @Makoto: In reply to `"Another unsolved problem, IMO, is the frequent edit problem" Why do you think so?`-- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/downvoting-for-a-perfectly-legitimate-question-just-because-one-thinks-the-op-is#comment25006_6866

Comment: @Hurkyl I am *not* frequently editing my questions. This cannot be a problem.

Comment: @Hurkyl "@Makoto: In reply to "Another unsolved problem, IMO, is the frequent edit problem" Why do you think so?-- http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/downvoting-for-a-perfectly-legitimate-question-just-because-one-thinks-the-op-is"

This question was more edited than it.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/why-are-vector-spaces-not-isomorphic-to-their-duals

Comment: @Makoto: I wrote to you a thousand times already, I don't hate you. This has nothing to do with that thread you linked, which I find overly broad. You should learn from the user Katlus and actually sit down and prove theorems on your own. You keep insisting that I hate you, and that this is some sort of witch hunt in order to allow yourself to believe that you have no faults of your own in ending up at a situation like this. Good luck with that. Keep posting meta threads asking why and why and why... I hope that someday you will at least read the answers and comments.

Comment: Let me explain one last time, the problem is that you refuse to accept the fact that the community is more than just you. You keep treating the site as if it was your own personal blog, and you post and post and do whatever you want without caring about any **social convention**. I would say that it might damage your reputation, but I doubt there is anything left to damage by this point. I am not going to answer your comments in this thread anymore. I have written the same thing about a zillion times now, over a billion meta threads. Others have too. Good luck.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "I am not going to answer your comments in this thread anymore."
I'm not surprised.
I am/was not using this site as my personal blog.
I am/was expecting the members of this site to answer my questions and accepted answers of theirs if I thought they were valid. (to be continued)

Comment: @AsafKaragila However, even your so called "personal blogging" is encouraged by this site as you know.
"Since Stack Overflow launched, we've been trying to explain that it's not just a Q&A platform: it’s also a place where you can publish things that you’ve learned: recipes, FAQs, HOWTOs, walkthroughs, and even bits of product documentation, as long you format it as a question and answer." http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/

Comment: @AsafKaragila One of my motivations for asking questions in this site is to provide answers for questions by other members by using my questions.

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43929/why-are-projective-morphisms-closed

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241711/how-can-i-prove-formally-that-the-projective-plane-is-a-hausdorff-space

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238239/a-property-of-the-radical-closure-of-a-field

Comment: @MakotoKato The MSE community standards may not coincide with the standards on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Why?

Comment: @MakotoKato Why not? Different places have different norms and cultures.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker OK, I misunderstood(and perhaps you, too). It(the blog) is talking about stack exchange sites including MSE.

Comment: @MakotoKato It is, but community decisions on these matters trup global decisions made for a much larger userbase. You can read a lot of old discussions in meta with Jeff Atwood on how independent MSE should be.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I would like to know the reason why "blogging" or "publishing" is discouraged in MSE if that is the case.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Apparently you think "blogging" is discouraged in this site.
I will delete all of my answers to my questions except those I referred to in my answers for other members' questions.
I hope you would be satisfied with it.
I'm not kind of man who doesn't care about accusations against him in the name of the community he belongs to.

Comment: @AsafKaragila "Let me explain one last time, the problem is that you refuse to accept the fact that the community is more than just you. You keep treating the site as if it was your own personal blog, and you post and post and do whatever you want without caring about any social convention."
I will delete all of my answers to my questions except those I referred to in my answers for other members' questions. I hope you would be satisfied with it. I'm not kind of man who doesn't care about accusations against him in the name of the community he belongs to.

Comment: Makoto, I think deleting answers to your questions would be viewed as vandalism. Leave them up, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm tired of this fuss. There are so many people who are against "blogging".

Comment: @MakotoKato Can you explain your "Apparently"to me?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker I thought you think blogging is discouraged in MSE. No?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I thought you didn't like what I was doing.

Comment: @Makoto: The edit problem has not been resolved, only patched. A *resolution* would require, at a minimum, that you acknowledge and preferably understand why others found frequent editing problematic. As far as I can tell, you have not done so. Thus, we only have a patch: an alternative that both sides are okay with. The patch may very well hold forever and there might be no more incidents in regards to this problem, however....

Comment: @Makoto: the fact it hasn't been resolved in the sense I described is significant, because it is one of many manifestation of the deeper problem that you don't seem to respect or care for the community opinions and norms, a problem which continues to create new and fresh incidents.

Comment: @Hurkyl Leave me alone, Hurkyl. I'm not a criminal.

Comment: @MakotoKato What Iam thinking is irrelevant here. I want to know why something is "apparent". Are you psychic?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker OK, it is not apparent that you think blogging is discouraged in MSE. So what is your opinion on this? Do you think that blogging should be discouraged in MSE?

Comment: Makoto, I'm not sure what you are referring to when you write to me, "I thought you didn't like what I was doing". I don't have any objection to your posting questions on m.se; I don't have any objection to your posting answers to your own questions on m.se; I do object to your deleting answers.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I understand. I guess it was my misunderstanding.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was informed by the moderators that I would be suspended if I continue to delete my answers.
So I stopped deleting, and I undeleted the answers I had deleted. Regards,

Answer (score 19):

I generally believe that questions and answers should be voted on based on mathematical content (including presentation and pedagogy) alone and not on personalities and/or prior perceived transgressions committed on the website.

That said, it can sometimes be surprisingly difficult to maintain a separation of those two.

Furthermore, people have the liberty to vote as they see fit and so each person must come to their own decision and reconciliation of these matters.

While best practices are nice to have and may have some small effect on overall voting patterns, little can (or should) be done to enforce them, except in the most extreme of cases.

Answer (score 10):

MSE is a place for people who want to learn mathematics and for people who want to help others to learn mathematics do so. This should be obvious, but it is too often ignored. From this perspective, it should be clear that voting on questions only for content is not even an ideal aiming for.

Here is a quick test anyone can (but should not) do: Find the best question, however you judge that, you can find on MSE and simply post it three time in a row. Given that each of thess questions is a shining piece of perfection, they should all gather upvotes galore and comments singing your praise. Of course, this won't happen for obvious reasons.

It should be clear that we show some leniency to new users we would not show experienced users that should be familiar with the laws of the land. It should be clear that it is legitimate for someone beginning to learn serious mathematics to be somewhat confused by Gödel's incompleteness theorems (and their popular expositions) and ask a question to that effect. It should also be clear that if you ask twenty questions about supposed flaws in these theorems, people will treat you as a crank.

Answer (score 8):

Sure. Ideally, which is what the comments and the other answers deal with, votes would reflect the content of the answer, and the quality of it.

Alas, this is not *really* the case, is it now? Can anyone argue that the famous $\mathsf{W}$ is any better than an answer which actually give a long and details explanation of something nontrivial? No. We can't argue that. The $\mathsf{W}$ is simply **popular**. And people need to understand that voting, while often and perhaps in most cases, reflect *to some extent* the mathematical validity of the content, also reflect how much the community simply likes the answer, or the user.

But let us talk for a moment on what's *really* going on in this meta thread. The OP opened this post after a comment I had left to him (which for some reason he took an extra effort to copy-paste into the reply box). This user has a very rich history of not caring what anyone else thinks. This user has a very long history of telling people to open meta threads, and to completely ignore anything that happens.

In a recent thread Brian M. Scott wrote in a comment "once burnt, twice shy". So what can we do?

Believe you me, when the problem just began with this user I was polite, and he ignored. Others were polite, and he ignored. I discussed this with the moderators, and they debated more while he continued to act. When meta threads were opened about him, he ignored. When he was actually suspended for his behavior one recently-former moderator quickly undid the suspension claiming it was unilateral and unjust. The suspension was re-applied, and the same thing happened again.

So what are we left with? We are left with a user that had a lord and protector from suspensions, continued to ignore **all** criticism, and continued to do whatever he pleases, despite continuing requests.

Sure, in the general case, in the ideal case, one shouldn't vote based on the user and their actions. But this is not the ideal case, and whatever this thread ends up reflecting will be used by that very borderline antisocial user to insist that things which transpired in the summer of 2012 are **now** unfair and must be reversed.

I don't know about any of you people, but I wouldn't let someone with a rap sheet full of arrests for theft the keys to my apartment. When a user continues on and on and there is no other way to make them understand that what they are doing is wrong then the community, like a sick body, has to react and try to defend itself somehow. To the common user [read: non-diamond moderators] the only remaining way is to downvote, close and delete.

So sure, generally one shouldn't downvote based on the user. But we tried this before, discussing the general case in the OP's case, and it led nowhere. We even tried to discussing the specific case and it haven't really led anywhere either. The OP will continue to behave and do whatever he wants, and none of us can do anything to change that.

---

**Historical reminders:** (Please don't bump these threads, it would serve no good now, but they can shed light on the origin of this meta post now)

1. [How much (self) editing is too much?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4612/how-much-self-editing-is-too-much)
2. [Where is the fine line between using and misusing?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/where-is-the-fine-line-between-using-and-misusing) (in particular [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/where-is-the-fine-line-between-using-and-misusing#comment17814_4653) which is relevant here.)
3. [Use of main-site comments for meta suggestions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4739/use-of-main-site-comments-for-meta-suggestions)

Comment: I see the downvotes accumulating, and I suppose that there are several people who will disagree with this. Alas the history cannot be changed (although it can be forgotten). I wonder why MK did not try and open such threads in August and July (during the "start a meta thread" period of his activity)...

Comment: *Can anyone argue that the famous W is any better than*... Yes I can (perhaps unsurprisingly, being the author) and I even kind of explained why in the comments to the answer. But I agree that the number of votes it received (and continues slowly but steadily to receive...) is a partly irrational phenomenon. More importantly and more to the point of the present thread, I agree very much with your approach in this post and with (the rest of) your explanations. In fact these strike me as being honest, remarkably self-examining, and going to the core of the situation. +1.

Comment: @did: Thank you very much. As for the example, I agree that the $\mathsf{W}$ answer is good. It is not trivial to capture this amount of mathematical insight in one letter. Alas, as you said the amount of votes it gathered is irrational. Equally I could have used Mariano's $\pi$ answer, which captures a deep point in one line, but I can't say it is better than many answers which have single digit vote counts.

Comment: Right. Let me not derail any further this thread from its main point.

Comment: I upvoted the $\mathsf{W}$ as a piece of community art. I would be worried if it would make up most of the did's rep and give him the power to vote to close, but as such there is nothing irrational about the many upvotes.

Comment: @Michael, I agree, but this comment just reinforces what I was writing to begin with. Votes are not necessarily about mathematical validity, or even "the level of mathematics involved".

Answer (score 5):

Moderation tends to be conservative. While often a good thing, it also means that I (and I assume Asaf as well) have little expectation that complaints about a pattern of misbehavior will lead to anything unless an *individual* incident is sufficient to provoke moderator action on its own.

We are also considering a situation where the user is particularly unreceptive to criticism and complaint.

This leaves downvotes as the only means of expressing dissatisfaction that is likely to have an effect.

While "purity" of voting is a nice ideal, I believe that retaining that purity is a greater evil than double-purposing downvotes as an outlet for this sort of expression.

Thus, I conclude that in situations meeting the above conditions, reacting to misbehavior with downvotes is desirable, until either

- The user becomes receptive to criticism
- There is overt moderator reaction inspiring confidence the situation will be resolved (e.g. by action against the misbehaving user, or satisfactorily refuting the claims of misbehavior)

And what remains to be clarified is the best downvoting patterns to use in reaction.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the particulars of this case. However in general I think the votes should mainly reflect the quality of the posts and the author's behavior in other threads shouldn't have much effect (though it is understandable that other users can be come harsher in judging the user's posts if the user is regularly misbehaving).

If a user is really misbehaving then you should inform the moderators to take action about it. If a user is repeatedly abusing the site's features and explaining this to the user doesn't change the user's behavior then the user can be temporarily suspended. If the temporary suspensions doesn't make the user understand that the behavior is not acceptable then the suspension can be made permanent. It shouldn't get to the point that users would need to use their votes to tell the user that such behavior is not acceptable.

Comment: In this case the user was suspended, but the suspension was reversed, twice, as a recent thread indicated. Of course suspending a user five months after is useless, and I don't think anyone wants that now. Alas when the time was right for it, it just didn't happen for one reason or another. What do you suggest now?

Comment: @Asaf, I think the cases varies a lot, so it is hard to give a general rule. There are two outcomes possible outcomes at the end: either the user will change behavior to avoid abusing the site or will be permanently suspended (which should be avoided as much as possible). Temporary suspensions is part of the mechanism to make the user move towards the first. However it is not sufficient by itself. The goal is to make the user understand that the behavior is not acceptable to the community and why it is so. As I see it the temporary suspension is a tool to make the user understand that

Comment: Yes. I agree very much with this. However the time for suspensions is over. The problem is no longer a meta headliner but rather a page 8 story. Pushing a suspension will get it back and incite another drama. People just got tired from trying to deal with this user. This user who wouldn't even acknowledge that he has made **any** mistake. That sounds insane to me.

Comment: the issue is a serious one and if the user values his participation in the community he would reconsider his behavior. By itself suspension is much less constructive. (Suspension period can be set manually, and I think in scientific sites 2 days seems a more reasonable period to start with, it is light.)

Comment: If you are bored, you can read through the [following meta thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6755/does-getting-a-lot-of-downvotes-have-actual-effects-on-a-question-or-the-op) which has recently tried to re-discuss the events of the summer, as if they are unbeknown to the OP.

Comment: I see, as I said I am not familiar with the particulars of this case. One thing that can help is to make it clear to the user that the general community has a negative view of his behavior. For example, a meta post asking "Do you think [this behaviour] is acceptable?". Sometime the misbehaving users feel that the objecting parties' views are not shared by general community. Avoiding making it a general issue can also be helpful, i.e. in place of arguing over whether some behavior is bad in general we can argue that the community of this particular site views it as unacceptable. ps: thanks.

Comment: There has been too many of these comments, and a meta thread (which I have linked in my answer) that actually referred to the user specifically because his behavior was unprecedented. Despite a good consensus that people disagree with the way he was acting, the only moderator outcome was Bill's Sandbox thread. No suspensions were issued (well, they were, but reversed in an internal lack-of-communication that was typical with one recently former moderator). The mainpage editing stopped, and people soon left the memory of the events behind, but the behavior is still the same to this day.

Comment: @Asaf, if I understand correctly the original issues were: 1. too much editing, 2. answering own question, 3. not receptive to comments about these. I think 1 is a problem, 2 [is completely OK](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), need to look further to see how serious 3 was. It might be helpful to try to fix these one by one in place of all of them together, starting from the most important one which is too much editing. ps: maybe we can ask for a feature request to avoid users making too many edits in a day so the edits are more significant.

Comment: No, the issues began with the user editing *way* too much. The second issue was that his questions were mainly motivated by self-interest, and for the most part were ended up open because one or two experts said they were interesting (although apparently solving open problems does not merit a link to arXiv). The user would treat this site as a blog owned by him, and would post insanely long answers and convoluted posts with links and definitions from other posts, it was a tangled web. The last issue was the worst, and still is (if you remove "about these." from it).

Comment: The edits are not an issue anymore thanks to the Sandbox on the meta site. However I still fail to see how so many users wrote so many long answers before that, and how it was possible for me to write and work on answers and proofs for a full week before actually posting them. And I am more than certain that I am not the only user who did/does that.

Comment: @Asaf, down-votes for such posts seems fine, they can be interpreted as being about the way the posts are written rather than the behavior (hard to read, not self-contained, etc.). 

Regarding *way* too much editing, that is a serious issue. I think asking the user to update the posts only after more careful thought and therefore less frequently is reasonable, plus temporary suspension if the user doesn't change behavior (but as I said, I am not very familiar with particulars and surely the moderators can make a more appropriate decision).

Comment: Yes, all that happened in the past, but none of that helped, as I said. To show how much the user regarding this site as a personal blog, let me tell you of the time he posted a plain discussion request and insisted it was on-topic. After being heavily downvoted, dramatized on meta, and whatnot, several users worked to edit the post to a vastly more reasonable question. Some months later, the user asked on the meta why is the question downvoted (and of course got a nice reap of reputation from pity votes).

Comment: @Asaf, yes, I know down-votes leading to positive reputation is annoying (counter-voting). I don't understand why a question with negative total vote should end up increasing reputation. I guess if the negative reputation resulting form a down-vote was equal to positive reputation resulting from an up-vote the case wouldn't be that annoying. ps: I think focusing and solving these issues one by one can be more effective.

Comment: Kaveh, rest assured that this is not just Asaf's personal crusade against Makoto. IMHO he speaks for a sizable fraction of the community.MK could be a valuable contributor, if he used his knowledge solely to answer others' questions, and/or asked his own in a way that would make it sound like help is actually welcome. Instead he is using the site as a personaly study diary/blog. I could (and do) just ignore him. But, no, he has to start these meta threads accusing the rest of us of foul play.

Comment: @kaveh: I'm not voting on your answer, but I do not think that we should rely on the moderators to choose the tone of the community. In my opinion, the point of the voting mechanism is to allow the overall community to decide such things. It's improper to go around downvoting all posts by a given user, but downvoting individual posts that you feel misrepresent the purpose of the site is most direct way to express that opinion. Polite comments, when they can be written, can and should also be used to explain the purpose of the downvotes.

Comment: @Kaven: Just because something shouldn't happen doesn't mean it won't happen! Also, after reflecting on the issue, I believe there is merit to having moderators act only in the extreme cases, leaving the more moderate cases to the community through comments and voting. How much merit? On that point I'm not sure.